# Javadocs and jdk mismatch on NavigableSet/Map?

Tags: java, collections

The [NavigableSet API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) state that methods `headSet`,`tailSet(E)`,`headSet(E)` and `subSet(E, E)` return a `NavigableSet`.

In Eclipse, I get a type mismatch error, although I use the 1.6_20 jdk and have my compiler compliance set to 1.6, so I have to "downgrade" the return value to `SortedSet`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Solved, i actually missed the boolean in the method signatures. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misread the javadoc. There two headSet methods, one returns SortedSet and the other returns NavigableSet. The same for the other methods you mentioned.